# Removing double space but not new line

Tags: javascript

I have used script to remove the double spaces. but this script is removing the new line also along with the space.

```
Suppose Input is "\s\s\n\n"
Script's output is "\s"
Desired Output "\s\n\n"

That I simply want to remover double space but not new line.
Want to skip new line.
```

`function clean(f) {
f.value=f.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s\s+/g,' ');
return true;
}`

Comment: `\s` matches `\t\n\v\f\r`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#endnote_equivalent_s

Comment: `\s` is any [white space character (see the Character Escapes section)](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml), including newlines, tabs, vertical tabs, linefeeds, etc. as well as `' '`.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently using `\s` which expunges any whitespace. If you wish to remove double or greater spaces whilst retaining all `\n` you can use the following:

```
replace(/ {2,}/g,'')
```